# Indexing many tables with SOLR 4.0 and then joining them during the query?

Tags: java, sql, solr, lucene

How is it possible to index many tables in SOLR 4.x (or greater), if the tables are not associated to each other?

Or is this approach wrong?

For example if I have tables about

```
tableShop
tableProduct
tableBook
tableWhatever
```

`Shop`, `Product` and `Book` are associated to each other, but `tableWhatever` is not associated, but I need to index it too.

Or maybe some books in `tableBook` are not assigned to any row of `tableShop`, how can I index them with SOLR???

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on your business model. With the latest versions of solr, you can use the cores to separate documents with different schema. But what makes a document usually depends on your view of the Entity and how search happens on that entity.

In your case, you can model each table to be a document, and query the collection separately. 
If you have to query which books do not have a shop assigned to them, you have to go for denormalizing your tables and creating a different schema combining the entities from the two tables. (or n tables).
Solr 4.0 allows join but because of that, do not take the route of modelling the relational database schema directly on to solr schema